# executable jar made by STS errors out

Tags: linux, java-8, spring-batch

I made java-batch on STS in Windows, and transfer jar(made by maven install) and property files to CentOS(ver,7).
When executed, error occurred. Logs are below:
**note**
BBBB01 is program name.

Can somebody help me..!

```
YYYY-MM-DD 13:49:33,413 ERROR CommandLineJobRunner - Job Terminated in error: Error creating bean with name 'BBBB01Configuration': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private org.springframework.batch.core.repository.JobRepository com.batch.xxxxx.BBBB01Configuration.jobRepository; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'jobRepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.jdbc.support.MetaDataAccessException: Could not get Connection for extracting meta data; nested exception is org.springframework.jdbc.CannotGetJdbcConnectionException: Could not get JDBC Connection; nested exception is org.apache.commons.dbcp.SQLNestedException: Cannot load JDBC driver class '${batch.jdbc.driver}'
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'BBBB01Configuration': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private org.springframework.batch.core.repository.JobRepository com.batch.cilabo.BBBB01Configuration.jobRepository; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'jobRepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.jdbc.support.MetaDataAccessException: Could not get Connection for extracting meta data; nested exception is org.springframework.jdbc.CannotGetJdbcConnectionException: Could not get JDBC Connection; nested exception is org.apache.commons.dbcp.SQLNestedException: Cannot load JDBC driver class '${batch.jdbc.driver}'
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:288)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1074)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)
```

====================
Concerting info i think is shown below:

**2 property files on src/main/resources.
1)batch.properties
2)log4j.properties

put on same directory as jar file on CentOS.

1) include HSQLDB's general settings(below) and ones of program specified.

```
# Placeholders batch.*
#    for HSQLDB:
batch.jdbc.driver=org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver
batch.jdbc.url=jdbc:hsqldb:mem:testdb;sql.enforce_strict_size=true
# use this one for a separate server process so you can inspect the results
# (or add it to system properties with -D to override at run time).
# batch.jdbc.url=jdbc:hsqldb:hsql://localhost:9005/samples
batch.jdbc.user=sa
batch.jdbc.password=
batch.schema=
batch.schema.script=classpath:/org/springframework/batch/core/schema-hsqldb.sql
...
```

**launch-context.xml

```
<beans ...>

    <context:property-placeholder order="1" location="classpath:batch.properties" />
    <context:property-placeholder order="2" location="classpath:log4j.properties" />
    <context:annotation-config/>

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.batch.XXXXXX" />
    <jdbc:initialize-database data-source="dataSource">
        <jdbc:script location="${batch.schema.script}" />
    </jdbc:initialize-database>

    <batch:job-repository id="jobRepository" />

    <import resource="classpath:/META-INF/spring/module-context.xml" />
```

**Manifest.MF made by maven-shade-plugin.

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Package: com.batch.XXXXXX
Build-Number: 1
Archiver-Version: Plexus Archiver
Built-By: xxxxxxxxx
Class-Path: ./
Created-By: Apache Maven 3.3.9
Build-Jdk: 1.8.0_102
Main-Class: org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.CommandLineJ
 obRunner
```

**parts of POM.xml
*properties

```
<properties>
    <maven.test.failure.ignore>true</maven.test.failure.ignore>
    <spring.framework.version>3.0.6.RELEASE</spring.framework.version>
    <spring.batch.version>2.1.7.RELEASE</spring.batch.version>
    <configFileBatch>batch.properties</configFileBatch>
    <configFilelog4j>log4j.properties</configFilelog4j>
</properties>
```

*build

```
<build>      
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.5</source>
                <target>1.5</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin> 

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <archive>
                    <index>false</index>
                    <manifest>
                        <packageName>com.batch.cilabo</packageName>
                        <mainClass>org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.CommandLineJobRunner</mainClass>
                        <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                        <classpathPrefix>lib/</classpathPrefix>
                    </manifest>
                </archive>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <finalName>BBBB01</finalName>
                <transformers>
                    <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                        <manifestEntries>
                            <Main-Class>org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.CommandLineJobRunner</Main-Class>
                            <Class-Path>./</Class-Path>
                            <Build-Number>1</Build-Number>
                        </manifestEntries>
                    </transformer>
                    <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.DontIncludeResourceTransformer">
                        <resource>.properties</resource>
                    </transformer>
                    <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.AppendingTransformer">
                        <resource>META-INF/spring.handlers</resource>
                    </transformer>
                    <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.AppendingTransformer">
                        <resource>META-INF/spring.schemas</resource>
                    </transformer>
                </transformers>
                <archive>
                  <manifestEntries>
                    <Class-Path>./</Class-Path>
                  </manifestEntries>
                </archive>
              </configuration>
            <version>1.7</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>shade</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Thx in advance.

Comment: try to load .properties with only one `context:property-placeholder` and specifying multiple locations as a comma-separated list

Comment: Hi, thx for hint. I challenged but not effective.
Finally, by another attempt i removed below from pom.xml then worked well.
<transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.DontIncludeResourceTransformer">
     <resource>.properties</resource>
</transformer>

i will study more about this reason...
thank you all!!

Comment: Have you tried using the "spring-boot-maven-plugin" to create the executable jar?

Comment: Late reply...no, i;ve used maven-shade-plugin for making executable jar after attempts. but i will try another time to use spring-boot-maven-plugin.